Selecting a Common ID where that ID Matches Certain Criteria
In the screenshot, Id is the primary key. There could be many of the same Participant__c values in this result set, each with a different Id.
What I'm trying to do is write a query that will return unique Participant__c values IF that particular Participant__c has records in this result set where the Survey_Index_Number__c values are 2001, 2003, and 2005, and their corresponding Completion_Status__c values are Complete. If Participant__c values MATCH that criteria, return that Participant__c value in a result set.
I'm just having a hard time figuring out the best way to approach this, and I'm leaning towards leveraging partitioning logic to do this, but I'm unsure how to start that.
EDIT: My resolution here. This query stores the current count of completed surveys by ContactId:
SELECT
    Participant__c as 'ContactId',
    COUNT(DISTINCT Survey_Index_Number__c) AS 'SurveyCountComplete'
FROM
    (SELECT
        Participant__c,
        Survey_Index_Number__c,
        Completion_Status__c
    FROM
        Contact_Salesforce c
    INNER JOIN
        Survey_Result__c_Salesforce sr on sr.Participant__c = c.Id
    WHERE
        sr.Completion_Status__c = 'Complete'
        AND Survey_Index_Number__c IN ('2001', '2003', '2005')) as CompletedSurveys
GROUP BY
    Participant__c



Seems like a simple aggregation. Filter out (with WHERE)  just the three years with Complete and then count by Participant and Year, At the end filter counts equal to 3 (with HAVING).

Please do not use images for data, use table markdown.

Please also show your desired results and your attempt.

i'm having a hard time trying to work out why you mention id at all since id seems to have nothing to do with the desired outcome..are you trying to hint at performance issues by mention of partitioning?, do you have any code ?if so publish it together with the table definition and sample data and desired outcome as text.

@P.Salmon I was just giving all the information to illustrate the big picture, and that includes the field names. Whether or not I needed to specifically say that ID was a primary key or not, I don't really care about that, if it doesn't matter to you it's all good, just ignore it. I have my answer in the answers section now, if you'd like to review.

@DaleK I cannot use table markdown because I don't have access to that. I'm a Salesforce developer but it can leverage SQL for its data manipulation, hence my post here. I basically create the SQL table from the Salesforce UI, but I don't have access to SSMS to see the table definition.

Table markdown is a feature of the question editor here which allows you to display data instead of using an image.

Assumed that you want unique Participant__c values if the table/result set has at least one row for each Survey_Index_Number__c values: 2001, 20023, 2005 with Completion_Status__c='Complete':
select Participant__c
from mytbl a
where  Survey_Index_Number__c in ('2001','2003','2005') 
and Completion_Status__c='Complete'
group by Participant__c
having count(distinct Survey_Index_Number__c )=3

